# Using NTFS External drive

Tags: macos, filesystem, ntfs, hdd

I'm new to MAC OS.

Using MacOSX 10.9.1 (Mavericks).

My external HDD is formatted with NTFS.

I need some rock-solid, free solution for reading and writing to this HDD. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Use ntfs-3g:

1. Install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)
2. Install fuxe4x and ntfs-3g

   ```
   brew install fuse4x && brew install ntfs-3g
   ```
3. Replace (with backup) the `mount_ntfs`:

   ```
   sudo mv /sbin/mount_ntfs /sbin/mount_ntfs.orig
   sudo ln -s /usr/local/sbin/mount_ntfs /sbin/mount_ntfs
   ```
4. Get info on fuxe4x-kext

   ```
   brew info fuse4x-kext
   ```
5. You should be given two lines based on your version that you need to run. Run these lines in Terminal.
6. Eject and remount the disk.

Comment: is that reliable solution?

Comment: @Tural Not entirely sure what you mean, but yes this works fine, although Mavericks complicated the install process a bit.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/3RX0UhjKTJDoXJWgM1k getting this error

Comment: not working on mavericks

Answer (score 3):

It's not free but I have had great success w/ this product: http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/

Answer (score 2):

If you have a seagate device, then [Paragon for Seagate](http://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/item/ntfs-driver-for-mac-os-master-dl/) is free and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the free '[Fuse for OSX](http://osxfuse.github.io/)' with '[NTFS-3G](http://macntfs-3g.blogspot.de/2010/10/ntfs-3g-for-mac-os-x-2010102.html)'. [This Page](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/NTFS-3G) describes the Installation.

I have used it for a couple of years (since 10.5 through 10.10) without any major Problems and can recommend both.

Answer (score 0):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/native-ntfs-osx/files/

Native solution. No 3rd party drivers or software installs.